# Headless Site is not getting created properly

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

I am creating a `Headless Site` inside `Headless Tenant` and its creating. However, I cant see few thing related to `Headless site`.

It neither shows `Settings` Section in `Site Grouping` nor `Rendering Hosts` folder inside settings->Service
[image]

[image]

Can anyone please suggest if I am missing anything ?

Comment: When you expand the Basic tab, do you not see Target host name, site name etc?

Comment: Hi @Sumit, I can see Site name, Valid for environment, Target hostname, Hostname etc. but can't see Settings section which is having "Predefined application rendering host" field. And there is no "Rendering Hosts" folder inside Settings, Services folder.